# How to replace the first n occurrences of one character with another using sed

Tags: sed

I have file with lines of text that have values that are zero filled.
I would like to replace all the leading zeros with spaces, but only for up to 7 times.

```
00000002:   <text>
```

Change the above to the following

```
       2:   <text>
```

I have the sed script

```
s/^0/ /;: loop s/ 0/  /;t loop
```

It replaces ALL the zeros.

The line

```
00000000:   <text>
```

is changed to

```
        :   <text>
```

I would like

```
       0:   <text>
```

and this would occur if the sed loop was able to be stopped after 6 loops.

How do I change the sed script to stop after 6 (n) loops.

Yes, I could brute force it and put in 6 versions of `s/ 0/  /`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is probably cheating, and I'm not sure it will work for all of your corner cases:

```
sed 's/^0/ /;s/0:/x:/;: loop s/ 0/  /;t loop;s/x:/0:/'
```

Actually, better yet:

```
sed 's/^0/ /;: loop s/ 0/  /;t loop;s/ :/0:/'
```

Comment: That's an idea I missed. Work right to left instead of left to right. The semicolon is a marker. I like the second version better too.

Comment: I still work left to right like you did, and I think it's better. I just added an extra `s/ :/0:/` after your own version.

Answer (score 2):

Perl is handy for this:

```
$ printf "%08d: blah\n" {0..12..4}
00000000: blah
00000004: blah
00000008: blah
00000012: blah
$ printf "%08d: blah\n" {0..12..4} | perl -pe 's/^0+(?=\d+:)/ " " x length($&) /e'
       0: blah
       4: blah
       8: blah
      12: blah
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/[^0]/\n&/;h;y/0/ /;G;s/\n.*\n//;s/ :/0:/' file
```

Comment: does is remove ONLY the 7 first leading 0 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/.*/ & /;s/\([²³]\)/\1o/g
   s/\([^[:digit:]]\)\(0\{1,7\}\)\([[:digit:]]\)/\1²\2³\3/g
: space
   s/²\( *\)0\(0*\)³/²\1 \2³/g
   t space
   s/²\( *\)³/\1/g
   s/\([²³]\)o/\1/;s/ \(.*\) /\1/'
```

The {1,7} specify the number of leading 0 you want to replace.

It replace all 0 of all number of the line. If it is only for the first number found

replace second line by this:

```
s/^\([^[:digit:]]*\)\(0\{1,7\}\)\([[:digit:]]\)/\1²\2³\3/
```

Comment: What do the superscript 2 and 3 denote?

Comment: I use it as delimiter because i cannot "change each occurence of char in a group by 1 specific char" whithout changing also the same old char in the rest of the string but i can change it if i know that it is between 2 delimiter. ² and ³ are my delimiter. I just securize first that they are not used by "escaping them" in a way they cannot be confused with our new sequence and set back at the end